# If a state is only "close to" an eigenstate of an operator, how many applications of the operator does it take to scramble the state?

Tags: quantum-state, mathematics, quantum-operation

Suppose we have an operator $U$, and a register $|\lambda\rangle$ in an eigenstate of $U$ with eigenvalue $\lambda=1$.  Repeatedly applying $U$ to $|\lambda\rangle$ does not affect $|\lambda\rangle$ - that is, $\langle\lambda|U^r|\lambda\rangle=1$ for all $r\in \mathbb{Z}$.

However suppose we have another register $|\mu\rangle$, which is only "close to" the eigenstate $|\lambda\rangle$.  That is, suppose we have a state $|\mu\rangle$ with $\langle\lambda|\mu\rangle=1-\delta$, for some small $\delta$.  I believe repeated applications of $U$ will eventually scramble $|\mu\rangle$ beyond recognition.  But, with respect to $\delta$, how quickly does this scrambling take place?

> How much do we have to know about $U$ and $\langle\lambda|\mu\rangle$ to be able to say anything about how big $r$ has to be before $\langle\mu|U^r|\mu\rangle\lt 1/3$?

I think this is akin to asking for more spectral properties of $U$.  Do we need to know about other eigenvalues of $U$ to answer how big $\delta$ has to be before $\langle\mu|U^r|\mu\rangle\lt 1/3$?

If we are able to prepare two separate registers, both initially "close to" an eigenstate, we can apply $U$ many times to the second register, and do a SWAP test between the first register $|\mu\rangle$ and the second register $U^r|\mu\rangle$.  If the SWAP test fails then we know that $r$ was large enough to scramble $U$.

I think this is a natural question that comes about from thinking of the BBBV theorem, but I'm not sure, and my only intuition is that if $U$ is more "connected" then $U^r$ acts rapidly to scramble $|\mu\rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the constraints of the problem, we have for $U$ unitary,
$$
\newcommand{\ketbra}[1]{\lvert#1\rangle\!\langle #1\rvert}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert#1\rangle}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle#1\rvert}
\newcommand{\sqoverlap}[2]{|\langle #1|#2\rangle|^2}
U=\ketbra{\lambda}+\sum_k e^{i\varphi_k}\ketbra{\lambda_k},$$
for some orthonormal basis $\{\ket\lambda\}\cup\{\ket{\lambda_k}\}_k$ and phases $\varphi_k\in\mathbb R$.
Given a target $\ket\mu$, the expectation value of $U^r$ equals

$$
  \bra\mu U^r\ket\mu=\sqoverlap{\mu}{\lambda} +
  \underbrace{
    \sum_k  e^{ir\varphi_k} \sqoverlap{\mu}{\lambda_k}
  }_{\equiv F_r}.
$$

Note also that the normalisation of $\ket\mu$ implies 
$$
  \sqoverlap\mu\lambda +
  \sum_k |\langle\mu|\lambda_k\rangle|^2 = 1
$$
The problem here is clearly in how to handle $F_r\in\mathbb C$, which has a pretty nasty behaviour: as a function of $r$, it oscillates wildly in the complex plane. Without any constraint on the possible $\ket{\lambda_k}$ and $\varphi_k$, or on the total dimension of $U$, pretty much any shape is possible (and here I cannot not link [this beautiful video by 3Blue1Brown](https://youtu.be/-qgreAUpPwM)). Just to give a mental picture of what I mean, here are two examples of what you can get when you plot $r\mapsto F_r$ for randomly sampled phases and overlaps, for a six-dimensional $U$:

[image]
[image]

<sup>The black dots correspond to the integer values of $r$, the blue line gives the value of $F_r$ for the real values in-between, and the red circle has radius $1-\sqoverlap{\mu}{\lambda}$. Only values of $r$ between $1$ and $100$ are shown.</sup>

Plotting even more points (all $r$ between $1$ and $10^3$), we see that the circle is essentially filled:

[image]

This is telling us that, in the general case, all we can say about $F_r$ is that it satisfies
$$
  |F_r|\le1-\sqoverlap\mu\lambda.
$$
Now, to get the probability of finding the initial state $\ket\mu$ unchanged after $r$ applications of $U$, we need to study the quantity 
$|\langle\mu|U^r|\mu\rangle|=\big|\sqoverlap\mu\lambda+F_r\big|$.
When $\sqoverlap\mu\lambda\ge1/2$ we know that $|F_r|\le\sqoverlap\mu\lambda$, and we thus have the bound
$$
  (2\sqoverlap{\mu}{\lambda}-1)^2 \le |\langle\mu|U^r|\mu\rangle|^2 \le 1,\quad \forall r.
$$
On the other hand, when the initial squared overlap is smaller than $1/2$, we can have $F_r=-\sqoverlap\mu\lambda$, and thus we get the trivial bound $|\langle\mu|U^r|\mu\rangle|\in[0,1]$.

Putting the two cases together, if we plot the possible values of $|\langle\mu|U^r|\mu\rangle|^2$ as a function of $p\equiv\sqoverlap\mu\lambda$ we get the following:

[image]

The interesting conclusion is that we *can* say something about the possible probabilities of a state remaining unchanged after a number of applications of the same unitary $U$, *provided that the initial overlap between the state and one of the eigenvectors of $U$ is big enough*.
Let me remark a few other things here:

- There is no loss of generality in our initial assumption that the eigenvalue of some $\ket\lambda$ is $1$. We can repeat the same identical argument by just taking an arbitrary eigenvector of $U$ with eigenvalue $e^{i\varphi}$, by only replacing each instance of $U$ with $U e^{-i\varphi}$. Most notably, *this does not affect the final result on $|\langle\mu|U^r|\mu\rangle|$*.
- If $\sqoverlap\mu\lambda=1-\delta$ with $\delta\ge0$ small, then the bound can be simplified to $|\langle\mu|U^r|\mu\rangle|^2\ge 1-4\delta$.
- Because we are not putting any constraint on $U$ or $r$ other than the initial overlap $\sqoverlap\mu\lambda$, we can also understand this result as telling us about the probability of $\ket\mu$ being unchanged upon a *single* application of a unitary $U$, or more generally about the probability of $\ket\mu$ being unchanged upon arbitrary applications of arbitrary unitaries all having an eigenvector close enough to $\ket\mu$.

---

Mathematica code to generate the plots of $F_r$:

```
dim = 5;
probs = 0.8 * # / Total @ # & @ RandomReal[{0, 1}, dim];
phases = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, dim];
otherFactor[probs_, phases_, r_] := Total[Exp[I r phases] probs];
Show[
 ParametricPlot[ReIm@otherFactor[probs, phases, r], {r, 0, 100}, 
  PlotPoints -> 60, MaxRecursion -> 10, 
  PlotRange -> ConstantArray[{-.9, .9}, 2]],
 Graphics[{ 
   Point@Table[ReIm@otherFactor[probs, phases, r], {r, 1, 100}],
   Thick, Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 0.8]
   }]
 ]
```

Comment: on second thought, this means that there *is* some scrambling, as the probability of the state remaining $|\mu\rangle$ is the square of $|\langle\mu|U^r|\mu\rangle^2$, which is then lower bounded by the *square* of the initial probabilities of finding $|\mu\rangle$ as $|\lambda\rangle$. I'll think more about it later

Comment: Thanks!  This is a really pretty derivation, that I'm surprised I understand as much as I do.  But I'm still struggling to square this with my intuition about Grover's algorithm.  In that case I think of $U$ as a combination of rotate-satisfying-assignment and invert-about-the-mean.  Clearly there's an $r$ that will have "scrambled" the state far enough away from the uniform distribution. With Grover's algorithm, is it the *combination* of the $Z$-rotation of the satisfying assignments *along with* the inversion about the mean, that gets us far away from the initial state?

Comment: @MarkS I agree that the connection with Grover's algorithm is interesting. As per my previous comment, the answer might lie in the fact that there might *be* some scrambling after all, because if you ask for the *probability* of $|\mu\rangle$ remaining itself, you have to square $\langle \mu|U^r|\mu\rangle$, which then gives you as lower bound a quantity that is the *square* of the initial one. This might correspond to a "maximum amount of scrambling" allowed by $U$, but I need to think a bit more about it

Comment: Thanks so much!  My application is to characterize the "mixing" properties of a unitary $U$ if we have a way to prepare a state "perturbed" from an eigenstate of $U$ by an amount $\delta$, as in [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/can-a-quantum-computer-easily-determine-the-mixing-time-of-the-rubiks-cube-grou).  What is the relationship, if any, between $\delta$, $r$, and the (TVD) mixing time?

Comment: @MarkS going back to this with a fresh mind I realised there were a few problems. See edits. The new bound makes much more sense, but is still interesting I think. The gist is that if a state is close enough to an eigenstate of $U$, it will not go too far from it, but if there isn't an eigenstate that is clearly privileged (i.e. corresponds to prob $\ge1/2$) then nothing can be said. Grover most notably falls into the latter category, and thus these arguments tell us nothing about it

Comment: Ahh.... hmm.  The uniform superposition is an eigenstate of the "invert-about-the-mean" ($U_s$) operator.  The "invert-about-the-mean" operator is an involution I think ($U_s^2=I$), so no matter how many states satisfy the oracle and see the $Z$-rotation, two applications of the "invert-about-the-mean" operator *without a further rotation therebetween* will bring us back to the prior state(?)  But Grover's algorithm is repetition of the $Z$-rotation of satisfying states ($U_\omega$ *and* the "invert-about-the-mean" operator ($U_s$).  Who can say what the eigenstate of $U_sU_\omega$ is?

Comment: @MarkS I'm not sure whether your comment is arguing against something I said or is just an observation, but regarding the eigenstates of $U_s U_\omega$, you can actually find explicit expressions for those. See [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/8623/55), and the similar answer on math.SE linked there. The idea is that $U_s U_\omega$ turns out to be an SU(2) rotation in the span of $|s\rangle$ and $|\omega\rangle$, one whose angles can be expressed in terms of initial and target states. Finding the eigenstates from there is pretty straightforward

Comment: Thanks! (It was just an observation).

Answer (score 2):

You certainly need to know all the other eigenvectors and eigenvalues. It's also important to know $|\mu\rangle$ and the nature of the operator $U$. Say, if $U$ is unitary, then the eigenvectors form an orthonormal set and their eigenvalues have modulus $1$. It's easy to resolve $|\mu\rangle$ along these orthonormal vectors.

To be concrete, suppose the orthonormal eigenvectors are $|\lambda_1\rangle, |\lambda_2\rangle, \ldots, |\lambda_n\rangle$, with eigenvalues $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n$. Now consider $\langle\lambda_1|\mu\rangle = 1 - \delta$ (where $\delta \in \mathbb R^+$). Contrary to your intuition, if $c_1 = 1$ and $|c_2|, \ldots, |c_n| = 1$, then after each application of the operator $U$, $\langle\lambda_1|\mu\rangle$ remains constant i.e, $1-\delta$. Repeated applications of $U$ would not *necessarily* scramble it.

Note that, in general, $\langle \lambda_1|U^r|\mu\rangle$ is not necessarily real and it doesn't make sense to directly compare it with a real number like $\frac{1}{3}$. Though, $|\langle \lambda_1|U^r|\mu\rangle|$ will always remain constant for a unitary transformation $U$ ($\forall r \in \Bbb N$), as all the eigenvalues of $U$ have a magnitude of $1$.

As $|\mu\rangle = a_1|\lambda_1\rangle + a_2|\lambda_2\rangle + \ldots a_n|\lambda_n\rangle$ (where $a_i \in \Bbb C$), the value of $\langle \mu|U^r|\mu\rangle$ would very much depend on the exact values of $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n$.

---

**Example**:

The phase shift ($R_\phi$) gate has eigenvalue $e^{i\phi}$ corresponding to eigenvector $|\lambda\rangle = |1\rangle$.

Say $|\mu\rangle = \frac{1|0\rangle + 99|1\rangle}{\sqrt{1^2+99^2}}$ and $|\langle 1|\mu\rangle| = \frac{99}{\sqrt {1^2+99^2}}$.

$$\therefore U^r|\mu\rangle = \frac{1|0\rangle + 99e^{ir\phi}|1\rangle}{\sqrt{1^2+99^2}}$$
$$\implies \langle 1|U^r|\mu\rangle = \frac{99 e^{ir\phi}}{\sqrt {1^2+99^2}}$$
$$\implies |\langle 1|U^r|\mu\rangle| = \frac{99 }{\sqrt {1^2+99^2}}.$$

So the magnitude of $\langle \lambda|U^r|\mu\rangle$ clearly remains constant, irrespective of $r$. Though, it certainly might pick up a phase factor upon each application of $U$.

Now, $$\langle \mu |U^r|\mu\rangle = \frac{1^2+99^2e^{ir\phi}}{1^2+99^2}.$$

Unless you take the magnitude it's not possible to compare this with $\frac{1}{3}$, and even then the value very much depends on $\phi$. Notice that if $\phi = 0$, $\langle \mu |U^r|\mu\rangle$ remains $1$ irrespective of how large $r$ is. If $\phi = \pi$, the magnitude keeps flipping between $1$ and $|\frac{1^2-99^2}{1^2+99^2}|$ as $r$ increases, without ever reaching below $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Ahh! Wow my intuition was pretty wrong. How do I square this with Grover's algorithm? Certainly the operators there are unitary, and if there's only one marked state eventually we get $|\langle\mu|U^r|\mu\rangle|\lt1/3$ (but it swings back up to $1−\delta$ again).  Does it always swing back?  I.e. for all unitaries $U$ and all states $|\mu\rangle$ *must* there be a positive integer $r\gt 1$ such that $|\langle\mu|U^r|\mu\rangle|=|\langle\mu|\mu\rangle|$? The special unitary group is continuous.

Comment: In Grover's algorithm the initial state $|\mu\rangle$ is a *uniform* superposition of all strings. Could you reframe your question in that context (and ask it as a new question)? In that case $|\langle\mu|\mu\rangle|$ is definitely $1$, and your question boils down to whether $U^r = I$ for some $r$. The answer is *yes*, iff $U$ is of [finite order](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/59722).

Comment: @MarkS It appears that Householder transformations are involuntary, so it's posssible that such a $r$ always exists. Though, I'm not sure whether product of two involuntary matrices i.e., $U_sU_\omega$ necessarily has finite order. In any case, I think you should ask that as a new question to allow for more elaborate answers.

Comment: Cool!  *involutary* ($U^2=I$).  But if I recall, in Grover's algorithm, there is not one fixed $r\gt 0$ that *necessarily* brings $(U_sU_\omega)^r|\mu\rangle$ back *exactly* to $|\mu\rangle$; rather, I think there's an $r$ that gets *pretty close* to $|\mu\rangle$.  I'll ponder your answer here, and find a way to ask a question closer to the applications that I'm thinking of.

Comment: @MarkS I've asked a question regarding this on [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3415232). BTW, in Grover's algorithm, there's an $r$ that gets *pretty close* to the target state $|\omega\rangle$, rather than $|\mu\rangle$ (or $|s\rangle$, as per Wikipedia). It may be very well possible that under certain conditions, for some $r$, the state re-coincides with the start state $|\mu\rangle$.

Comment: Though, I guess you're right when you say that repeated application of the operators might possibly bring it back very close to the start state $|s\rangle$ too, in all cases.

Comment: @MarkS about the question on Grover's algorithm, you can actually see pretty easily when there is such an $r$ when you write the evolution as an SU(2) matrix in the target/initial state subspace, which you can do as I show [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/8623/55). Using the notation there, to go full circle you need $\pi k/\alpha\in\mathbb N$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$, where $\sin\alpha$ is the overlap between initial and target states. If this is true, than you go back to the starting point after $r=k\pi/\alpha$ iterations

Comment: (this is equivalent to the question: given a rotation $R$ of $\mathbb R^2$ by an angle $\alpha$, when is there an $r\in\mathbb N$ such that $R=I$?)

Comment: @glS I think in your last comment you mean "when is there an $r\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $R^r=I$"?

Comment: @MarkS clearly, yes =). I hate not being able to edit comments